# After installing node.js browser can't load files in javascript folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

My vagrant box is running multiple localhost websites and now I'm trying to get Laravel Elixir set up. The issue is that after installing node.js on by Ubuntu 14.04 vagrant box, the javascript files on one of my websites (which stores its client-side javascript files in a /javascript folder) becomes inaccessible to my web browser. In fact, if I try to access any file in the site's root javascript folder, the vagrant server returns a 404 not found error. However, an /xyz/javascript folder is accessible.

My suspicion is that node.js caused apache to now treat root /javascript folders as folders that should only contain server-side code and so is cutting off access to the folder for security reasons. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

***update***
I guess I should note that said website with the /javascript folder is a decently old site. Could there be any incompatibilities with node.js?

Comment: Your claims make absolutely no sense at all.  This simply does not happen.  Node.js doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised by the behavior too. But I'm not making it up. The website with the /javascript folder works before "sudo apt-get install nodejs" is ran in the Ubuntu terminal, but afterwards the browser can't find any of the files in the /javascript folder.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you're making up the problem, I'm saying that your conclusions are wrong. Something else caused your permissions problem. Node doesn't have the concept of a doc root directory.